# More efficient/simplified dataframe rolling window calculation in Python

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

My multiindex df looks like this:

```
     Day 1        Day 2       Day 3       Day 4
     Var 1  Var2  Var1  Var2  Var1  Var2  Var1  Var2
A    1      2     3     4     5     6     7     8
B    9      10    11    12    13    14    15    16
```

...which I want to transform into a shiftig 3-day-window df, like:

```
     Day -2       Day -1      Day 0        
     Var 1  Var2  Var1  Var2  Var1  Var2  
A    1      2     3     4     5     6     
B    9      10    11    12    13    14    
A    3      4     5     6     7     8
B    11     12    13    14    15    16
```

...with two shifting windows (Day 1-3 and Day 2-4) with 3 days each. I have a working solution with for-loops so far, that loops over all days and all rows. As this consumes a lot of time: Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What becomes `Day 4` columns ?

Comment: Can be discarded, I just want a 3-day sliding window within 4 days (= 2 windows for A and B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to to append the `n-1` last columns to the `n-1` first columns and then change the column name:

```
def sub_n_days(col_name, n):
    return "Day {}".format(int(col_name.split(" ")[-1])-1)

out = df[days[:-1]].append(df[days[1:]]
                                .rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 1),
                                        level=0)) \
                   .rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 3), level=0)
```

**Explanations**

1. Define a function to substract `n` days for a given column name. Here is a simple one. I let you improve it according to your needs.

```
# col_name is the column name and "n" the number of days to subtract
def sub_n_days(col_name, n):
    return "Day {}".format(int(col_name.split(" ")[-1])-1)
```

2. Save the names of the first level column using `days = df.columns.levels[0]`
3. Select the `n-1` *first* columns using `df[days[:-1]]`
4. Select the `n-1` *last* columns using `df[days[1:]]`
5. Rename the `n-1` last column by subtracting one day. We use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)  and use the column parameters with a lambda function. We also specify the level used (here the level `0`).

   `df[days[1:]].rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 1), level=0)`
6. Then we append the result from 3 and 5 together using [`pd.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df[days[:-1]].append(df[days[1:]].rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 1),
                                        level=0))
```

7. As step 5, we rename the columns using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)
8. One last time, we rename index using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

---

*Full code*

```
# import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dummy dataframe
col_1 = ["Day {}".format(i + 1) for i in range(9)]
col_2 = ['Var1', 'Var2']
col = [(c1, c2) for c1 in col_1 for c2 in col_2]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 36).reshape(2,18), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col))
print(df)
#   Day 1      Day 2      Day 3      Day 4      Day 5      Day 6      Day 7      Day 8      Day 9
#    Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2
# 0     0    1     2    3     4    5     6    7     8    9    10   11    12   13    14   15    16   17
# 1    18   19    20   21    22   23    24   25    26   27    28   29    30   31    32   33    34   35

# Colect days columns names
days = df.columns.levels[0]

# Define our own function to substract days of a given column name
def sub_n_days(col_name, n):
    return "Day {}".format(int(col_name.split(" ")[-1])-1)

# Apply the computation
out = df[days[:-1]].append(df[days[1:]]
                                .rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 1),
                                        level=0)) \
                   .rename(columns=lambda x: sub_n_days(x, 3), level=0) \
                   .rename(index={0: "A", 1: "B"})
print(out)
#   Day 0      Day 1      Day 2      Day 3      Day 4      Day 5      Day 6      Day 7
#    Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2  Var1 Var2
# A     0    1     2    3     4    5     6    7     8    9    10   11    12   13    14   15
# B    18   19    20   21    22   23    24   25    26   27    28   29    30   31    32   33
# A     2    3     4    5     6    7     8    9    10   11    12   13    14   15    16   17
# B    20   21    22   23    24   25    26   27    28   29    30   31    32   33    34   35
```